# Accessing a dataframe column with index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have dataframe with A,B,C as its columns. I have set an index on it using

```
df.set_index('A')
```

Now I want to filter rows using a condition statement like

```
df[df.loc['A'] == '10001']
```

This gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [A] is not in the [index]'
```

How do I apply a condition on the column I have set as an index?

Comment: Use `df.index`?

Comment: df[df['A'] == '10001']
?

Comment: `df=df.set_index('A')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this df

```
        val
A   
10001   5
10002   6
10003   3
```

You can filter the rows using

```
df[df.index == '10001']
```

You get

```
        val
A   
10001   5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify 'inplace=True'

```
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
```

otherwise it doesn't persist.